# Android Studio ¿Debo resideñar las imágenes de mi app con distintos tamaños?

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen

Tengo en mi app una actividad la cual contiene imágenes circulares parecidas a las de la app "Pedidos Ya".

**Adjunto foto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber justamente lo que pregunto en el título, porque estoy por asociarme con un diseñador gráfico para el diseño de mis imágenes. Debo pedirle dichas imágenes con distintas medidas? O puedo lanzar mi app con un solo tamaño de imágen para estas imágenes circulares, sin que afecte a la visión de las mismas?

**Entiendo que quizá no sea el formato correcto de pregunta para el sitio, pero realmente necesito solucionar este problema. Agradezco su lectura y cada una de las respuestas!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas crear imágenes para dispositivos de distintos tipos de tamaños y densidades, **actualmente lo mejor es requerir imágenes con formato .svg**

A partir de estas imágenes localiza tu directorio de recursos /drawable y mediante el botón derecho abre el menú contextual : `New` > `Vector Asset` o `Image Asset`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de Image Asset puedes generar imagenes incluso combinando una imagen (Foreground Layer) y un fondo (Backgroind layer)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En base a la imagen fuente puedes generar imagenes para distintas densidades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El uso de imágenes .svg tiene muchas ventajas, como que es ligero, puede escalarse a cualquier tamaño sin perder el detalle de la imagen (pixelación), puedes usar herramientas como http://www.inkscape.org/ para crear este tipo de gráficos.

revisa también:

[Cómo agregar gráficos vectoriales de varias densidades](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio?hl=es-419)

[Utilizar imagenes vectoriales en Android](https://geekytheory.com/utilizar-imagenes-vectoriales-android)

Comment: Gracias por el agregado de información Jorge. Me dirías por que actualmente lo mejor es .svg? (Formato el cual desconocía hasta recién) Y también me gustaría que me des algún link con el cual pueda investigar más sobre este tema porque realmente no lo comprendo.

Comment: @TomasM he editado mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes importar tus imagenes con android studio el cual te creara las diferentes dimensiones necesarias para el tipo de pantalla:

[image: Clic derecho sobre drawable]

Luego seleccionar la imagen y android te mostrara las diferentes dimenesiones a crear:

[image: Seleccionar la imagen]

Comment: Tremendo! Desconocía totalmente eso. Muchisimas gracias, voy a probarlo aunque me gustaría hacerte una pregunta antes de votarte. Si subo una imágen de 50px x 50px, esta se redimensiona al igual que si subo una de 200px x 200px por ejemplo? Quiero decir: Tendré algun problema?

Comment: Si, debes tener en cuenta que android tratara de usar la mejor dimension para tu imagen pero si tu imagen al importarla s muy pequeña y la quieres usar como un icono grande se vera pixeleada

Comment: Buenisimo muchas gracias!